# Don't want time on JTable

Tags: java, swing, date, jtable

When I fetch data from database it gives me `Date` as `04/01/2014 00:00:00` and it is displayed on `JTable`.

Now I want to display only date on table and discard the time.

How can I do it?

EDIT:

```
public Vector getDateCustomer(String name,String name1)throws Exception
{
Vector<Vector<String>> getdatecustomerVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

Connection conn = dbConnection();

pre1=conn.prepareStatement("select * from Debit where Date "
    + "between CDate(?) and CDate(?) order by Date ASC");
pre1.setString(1, name); // bind param 1
pre1.setString(2, name1); // bind param 2

ResultSet rs1 = pre1.executeQuery();
while(rs1.next())
{
Vector<String> getdatecustomer = new Vector<String>();
getdatecustomer.add(rs1.getString(1)); 
getdatecustomer.add(rs1.getString(2)); 
getdatecustomer.add(rs1.getString(3)); 
getdatecustomer.add(rs1.getString(4)); 
Date myDate=(Date)format.parse(rs1.getString(5).substring(0, 10));
getdatecustomer.add(format.format(myDate)); 
getdatecustomer.add(rs1.getString(6)); 
getdatecustomerVector.add(getdatecustomer);
}
/*Close the connection after use (MUST)*/
if(conn!=null)
conn.close();

return getdatecustomerVector;
}
```

This is how I am getting values from database.

Getting error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-01-01"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at shop.DBEngine.getDateCustomer(DBEngine.java:548)
    at shop.DCSTable.<init>(DCSTable.java:127)
    at shop.DCS.actionPerformed(DCS.java:273)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: The best approach is to use a `TableCellRenderer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
Date myDate=(Date)format.parse(rs1.getString(5).substring(0, 10));
getdatecustomer.add(format.format(myDate));
```

By

```
getdatecustomer.add(format.format(rs1.getDate(5)));
```

EDIT:

I suggest you, do not use such kind of tricks. This trick may not be useful in the future. Please learn how to use renderer. And use only proper TableCellRenderer as @MadProgrammer suggest you.

Comment: no - don't store a string representation (formatted or not) in the model: that's the task of a renderer!

Comment: I am just giving him a trick to solve the problem. May be he is unable to handle TableCellRenderer

Comment: `May be he is unable to handle TableCellRenderer` - and how do you learn if people only give you tricks, and not the proper way to solve the problem?

Comment: The purpose of the model is to hold the raw, unformatted data.  You never know how the application will need to interact with this data in the future. The purpose of the view is to format/display the data, this is where the decisions about how the data should be changed should be made, this is the responsibility, in this context, of the `TableCellRenderer`. Short term hacks ALWAYS come back to bite you in the rear end.

Answer (score 5):

**Based on original question**

Two things you can do.

1. Make sure that the table model is returning `Date.class` for the given column.  The default behaviour of the `JTable` would be to take the objects `toString` result and display it within the cell.
2. If you can't do that or if the result is not what you want, you should create yourself a custom table cell renderer which can return the format you want...

For example

```
public class DateTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    protected static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    private DateFormat format;

    public DateTableCellRenderer() {
        this(DATE_FORMAT);
    }

    public DateTableCellRenderer(DateFormat format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value instanceof Date) {
            value = format.format((Date)value);
        }
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        return this;
    }

}
```

Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), in particular [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more details

The best way to apply this renderer might be to set it as the default render for a particular class type, in this, `java.util.Date` or if you know that it is `java.sql.Date`.

```
table.setDefaultCellRenderer(Date.class, new DateTableCellRenderer());
```

This will assume that the `TableModel`'s `getColumnClass` is returning the correct class type for the columns.  If not, then you'll need to set the renderer directly the specific column...

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(indexOfDateColumn).setCellRenderer(new DateTableCellRenderer());
```

Personally, I would prefer the first option over the second...

**Based on updated question**

Don't change the data types coming from the database, these are important and you may actually want to interact with them in some way which is beyond the capabilities of `String`.

The purpose of a model is to represent the data, the model should not care in what format the data is presented in, in fact, the more you can keep the data in it's raw format the better.

The view is responsible for deciding how that data should be represented, in this case, that's the role of the `TableCellRenderer`

Comment: Look at the `TableModel` interface and its `Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)` method.

Answer (score 4):

Then you should use a `SimpleDateFormat`. For instance:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String s = format.format(yourDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can implement your own `TableCellRenderer` , you can extends [DefaultTableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) creating your custom `DateCellRenderer` override it `getTableCellRendererComponent()`. And for formatting the date use [SimpleFormatDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can set this Renderer for specific column or for all instances of `Date.class`.

More information read the official tutorials [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Answer (score 2):

Create a simple renderer by overriding the setValue() method of the default renderer:

```
public class YMDRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    private Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd");

    public void setValue(Object value)
    {
        //  Format the Object before setting its value in the renderer

        try
        {
            if (value != null)
                value = formatter.format(value);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {}

        super.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

To take advantage of this type of rendering by using reusable code check out [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/). Then all you need to do is specify the formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd");
TableCellRenderer renderer = new FormatRenderer( format );
```

Edit:

As mentioned by nachokk if you are going to go to the trouble of creating a completely custom renderer then you should probably use an instanceof check to make sure you are formatting the proper class:

```
public class YMDRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    private Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd");

    public void setValue(Object value)
    {
        //  Format the Object before setting its value in the renderer

        if (value instanceof Date)
        {
            value = formatter.format(value);
        }

        super.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: empty catch? what would be the value of `value` in `super.setValue` if an exception happen?

Comment: @nachokk, Then the value that is passed into the method will be used and the default renderer will just use the toString() method of the object. Agreed, you don't generally have an empty catch, but the renderer should display something and a message like "invalid formatting" is probably not a reasonable value. So by using an empty catch you get the default behaviour of the renderer.

Comment: +1 mm right i see  ,in that way you don't need to use `instanceof`,

Comment: @nachokk yes, you are right, in this example I could have checked for an instance of Date since it is an example of a specific renderer. I showed the basic code from the FormatRenderer class. That class is a general class for using any Format object so the value to be rendered could be a Date, Number, String... So handling the IllegalArguementException was just a general way to handle any kind of formatting. Then the only code that needs changing is the Format.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using a `DefaultTableModel`, which uses a `Vector` of `Vector`s of `Object`s.  You are also probably using `ResultSet.getString(int column)` instead of `ResultSet.getDate(int column)`.  The `getDate` method returns a `java.sql.Date` object, which has no time-of-day data. You might also be using an `Object[][]` using the simplest `JTable` constructor.

Subclass the more flexible `AbstractTableModel` class instead.

So, take these steps:

1. Create a class that represents in Java the data in the row.  Use the correct classes for the data. Don't default to `String`. For the `Date` here, use `java.sql.Date`.
2. Use the appropriate `getXXX` methods of `ResultSet`.
3. Extend `AbstractTableModel`  to a new `TableModel` that takes a `List` of your new class.
4. Have your new `TableModel` return the right `Class<?>` in its `getColumnClass(int column)` method.
5. As other responders suggest, write your own renderer if Swing's default doesn't serve you.